# Insert image inside alert without resize the element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How I should stylize this:

```
<div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
  <div class="media">
    <img th:if="${categoria.icone}" th:src="@{/imagem/download/__${categoria.icone.id}__}" width="64px" height="64px" class="mr-3" th:alt="${categoria}">
    <svg th:unless="${categoria.icone}" width="64px" height="64px" class="bd-placeholder-img mr-3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64">
      <title>Placeholder</title>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect>
      <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">#</text>
    </svg>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h5 th:each="t : ${categoria.nome}" th:if="${#strings.equals(#strings.substringBefore(t.idioma,','), #strings.replace(#locale,'_','-'))}" th:utext="${t.conteudo}"></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In a way the image do not change the height of the alert element, but it's displayed with the edges outside the alert area. (the tags `img` and `svg` are never displayed at the same time, they are dependent of the result of the `th:if` conditional)

Comment: what did you mean displayed with the edges outside the alert area? Would you mind explained a bit?

Comment: something like that: https://imgur.com/a/byZ0z0n

Comment: I have added explanation and reference which you may refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean you would like a CSS to style the alert box similar to this effect?

```css
.alert {
  min-width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.media {
  height: 100%; /* fill up height */
}

.media-body {
  margin-left: calc(64px + 1em + 8px); /* image width + left of img + any margin */
  
  /* align vertical center */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%; /* fill up height */
}

.media-body h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

img, svg {
   position: absolute;
   top: -7px;
   left: 1em; /* you may use em if you wants the position have a relationship with container font-size */
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
  <div class="media">
<img th:if="${categoria.icone}" th:src="@{/imagem/download/__${categoria.icone.id}__}" width="64px" height="64px" class="mr-3" th:alt="${categoria}">
    <svg th:unless="${categoria.icone}" width="64px" height="64px" class="bd-placeholder-img mr-3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64">
      <title>Placeholder</title>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect>
      <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">#</text>
    </svg>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h5 th:each="t : ${categoria.nome}" th:if="${#strings.equals(#strings.substringBefore(t.idioma,','), #strings.replace(#locale,'_','-'))}" th:utext="${t.conteudo}">something here</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the direction is right, here are some additional information that you may like to take it into account.

- The [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) compatibility if you need to support a variety of browsers. You may also refer to [this table](https://caniuse.com/#search=Calc)

The concept behind:

- container fixed height, smaller than the image
- image element height divide the overflow portion as margin
- absolute for positioning image: if you don't like absolute you may also use negative margin to achieve the same thing, the example is just a proof of concept and demonstrate one of the possibilities
- the flex is a modern and easy way to align item vertically, you may read the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for more details